# Ajax response to xml page to get title elements doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Can anyone tell me why I can't get the elements from an XML document? It doesn't print anything when I press the <kbd>et Title</kbd> button that i have implemented in the body section. Here's my code:

```
function MyF () {
            var xmlhttp;
            var txt,x,i=0;
            var xx;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else{
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    x = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("CD");
                    xx = x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE");
                    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xx;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",true);
        }
```

Comment: Define "not working". Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: Please post the relevant content of the XML file.

Comment: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/cd_catalog.xml) that's the xml file.@Quentin The answer to your question is when i open the web page i only have one button and one div tag that's empty.After clicking the button it should print the content of the first title tag in the xml file.As to the javascript console on the browser it doesn't register any errors.

Comment: @Quentin After 10 or so refreshes on the page the javascript console finally showed something."Protocol error: TypeError: can't access dead object".Now it started saying "Protocol error: TypeError: node is null".

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're mucking about with plain JS and not using [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for AJAX?

Comment: The assignment i was given strictly said only to use JS and Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

`xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement` is the problem of your troubles. Just use `xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName` and you should be fine.